# Jenkins CD Pipeline: How to execute particular steps just once a day

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-delivery

I have a (declarative) Jenkins Pipeline that is doing builds and tests continuously. When successful, the application should be deployed on particular test environments once a day, based on some schedule.

For instance, if the build was successful, and current time is

- between 11:00 and 14:00, deploy to TestA, but just once a day;
- between 14:00 and 18:00 deploy to TestB, but also just once a day;
- etc.

I would be able to do the time slot handling in some groovy code, but I'm not sure how to "remember" whether there already was a deployment in this time period as of today. Of course, it is useless to store that information in the workspace, since later builds may be executed somewhere else.

So what options do I possibly have?

1. Store some **marker file** in a shared network location, and check this file and its timestamp in later builds to decide whether a deploy is required. This would probably work, but introduces dependency to external resources.
2. Can I somehow **"mark" the Jenkins build** when doing deployment, so that following builds can iterate through previous build(s) and search for such marker? Like archiving some small text file with the build?
3. Alternatively, is there **any plugin** that supports this scenario?
4. Or any completely different idea?

This seems to be a frequent scenario in CD pipelines, so I wonder how this is done in the wild... Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 1):

You should have the build and deploy stages on separate pipelines. That way the build can occur independently, and the deployment can be triggered by the timer to run exactly once per day.

In this case you'd want the build pipeline to archive its artifacts, so that the deploy pipeline can always deploy a successful build. The [Copy Artifacts plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/copyartifact) can be used to get the build pipeline's artifacts into the deploy pipeline's workspace.